Strange full table scan statements in Oracle
I executed the following three statements in a single instance of Oracle 19c:
CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT \* FROM dba_objects;

CREATE INDEX ix_t_name ON t(object_id,  object_name, owner);

SELECT object_id, object_name, owner FROM t;

I want to know why the last query did not go through the index?????
when I added a primary key constraint on the object_id, SELECT object_id, object_name, owner FROM t;
This statement will be indexed, and I would like to know why. Thank you for your answer.

This fiddle does use the index.

The columns are nullable. Oracle Database doesn't index wholly null rows.
Thus it can't use an index scan, because there's a chance some rows will be missing from the index.
To overcome this, make at least one of these columns mandatory. This guarantees every row will be in the index.
create table t as select * from dba_objects;

create index ix_t_name on t(object_id,  object_name, owner);

select column_name, nullable from user_tab_cols
where  table_name = 'T'  
and    column_name in ( 'OBJECT_ID', 'OBJECT_NAME', 'OWNER' );

COLUMN_NAME          N
-------------------- -
OWNER                Y
OBJECT_NAME          Y
OBJECT_ID            Y

set serveroutput off
set feed only
select object_id, object_name, owner from t;
set feed on

select * from dbms_xplan.display_cursor( format => 'BASIC LAST');

----------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name |
----------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |
----------------------------------

alter table t 
  modify object_name not null;

set feed only
select object_id, object_name, owner from t;
set feed on

select * from dbms_xplan.display_cursor( format => 'BASIC LAST');

------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name      |
------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |           |
|   1 |  INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| IX_T_NAME |
------------------------------------------


Your query:
SELECT object_id, object_name, owner FROM t;

does not have any WHERE, HAVING, or other filter clauses in it.  Indices are useful when starting off with a large number of records and then discarding ones which are not part of the result set.  In the case of your query, you are simply asking for the entire table, so Oracle is choosing to satisfy that request using a regular full table scan.
On the other hand, if your query were:
SELECT object_id, object_name, owner FROM t WHERE object_id = 1234;

in this case the index might be usable for a more rapid lookup of the record whose object_id is 1234.

This fiddle does use an INDEX FAST FULL SCAN for the OP's query.

But when I added a primary key constraint on the object_id, SELECT object_id, object_name, owner FROM t;
This statement will be indexed, and I would like to know why. Thank you for your answer.

@Zhangxin For your follow up question, the answer is that it really a moot point as to whether that select without filter uses any index or not; A full table scan or an index scan are likely to have very similar performance.  The usage of an index is more relevant when you have a query where the index substantially changes performance.
